# Error while using context in Mongo-Atlas Stitch

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch

I'm trying to create a stitch for a Mongo-Atlas cluster.

Here is the simple webhook function

```
exports = function(payload) {
   const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
   const cyber = mongodb.db("cyber"); 

};
```

unfortunately running this gives me the error

> TypeError: Cannot access member 'db' of undefined
>
> > trace:  TypeError: Cannot access member 'db' of undefined
> >         at exports (function.js:4:18)
> >         at apply ()
> >         at function_wrapper.js:3:10
> >         at :12:1

Basically the first get call returns `mongodb` as `undefined`.

Anybody has run into this issue?

Comment: I ran into it today and for me it still doesn't work. I check couple of times that I'm in correct Atlas cluster but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok this was silly.

The context name for my cluster was not `"mongodb-atlas"` but rather `"mongodb-atlas-production"`

Comment: A comment in the trigger editor when you first start writing your trigger says the following: "Note: In Atlas Triggers, the service name is defaulted to the cluster name." For me it worked to use my cluster name as the service name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are at MongoDb-Atlas, u can try first reading the documentation appended in your function definition.

> Functions run by Triggers are run as System users and have full access to Services, Functions, and MongoDB Data.
> [...]
> **Note: In Atlas Triggers, the service name is defaulted to the cluster name.**

It means that your `SERVICE_NAME` is the name of your **Cluster**.